# How to calculate total price of basket Vuejs Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have a store in which there is an array named `basketContents`

Like this:

```
state: {
basketContents: [
{
     name: .....
     quantity: 2
     price:1000
},
{
     name: .....
     quantity: 6
     price:120
},
.........
   ]
}
```

From this I want to calculate the total price of the whole basket and display it in a component is there an easy way to do so? The total price should also change whenever I change an items quantity.
I am new to this.

Comment: `let total = state.basketContents.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.quantity * val.price, 0)`

Comment: Where should I put this line of code?

Comment: Well ... after your code, also you have mistakes there like there should be `=` after `state` if this is a variable and also you don't have commas after your attributes in object

Comment: Thanks it worked I will put the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 getters: {
    total: state => {
      return state.basketContents.reduce((acc, val) => acc + val.quantity * val.price, 0) 
    }
 }
```

In your getters you can add that.

In your `.vue` file put:

```
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex';
// And put in computed:
// mix the getters into computed with object spread operator
...mapGetters([
   'total'
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a function named totalPrice in computed of the component where you want to show the total price:

```
  computed: {
   totalPrice() {
      return this.$store.state.basketContents.reduce(
        (acc, val) => acc + val.quantity * val.price,
        0
      );
    },
  },
};
```